# Carrierwave / Imagemagick / Ghostscript convert PDFs

Tags: imagemagick, carrierwave, ghostscript

First off I think this is a ghostscript issue but cross posting in imagemagick and Carrierwave.

Uploading images via Carrierwave and image processing with Imagemagick.

Trying to make a preview from the first page of a PDF.  There seems to be an issue with certain multi-page PDFs.

Here is my uploader:

```
def convert_to_image(height, width)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.read(current_path)[0]
  image.resize_to_fit(height,width).write(current_path)
end

version :pdf, :if => :pdf? do
  process convert_to_image: [700, 500]
  process :convert => :jpg
end
```

and fails with this:

MiniMagick::Invalid - `magick identify /var/folders/zw/j_y1s0tj643gmv4hbh5817wr0000gr/T/mini_magick20200627-71429-lpzoqa` failed with error:
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562. : app/uploaders/document_uploader.rb:83:in` convert_to_image'

After some digging tried to run `identify` from the CLI on the same files with a variety of results:

```
$ magick identify IVBF38119258.pdf
identify: Postscript delegate failed `[ghostscript library 9.52] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/zw/j_y1s0tj643gmv4hbh5817wr0000gr/T/magick-jw8gFt4B3DycFkMKjFWvQydx3jOspoqF%d' '-f/var/folders/zw/j_y1s0tj643gmv4hbh5817wr0000gr/T/magick-qkBx-zgVeMseaxcelWKlMN56JcjTQgGx' '-f/var/folders/zw/j_y1s0tj643gmv4hbh5817wr0000gr/T/magick-2g-lEqHui4gcC0fHefMkqamq009DIkON'': Error: /typecheck in --runpdf--
Operand stack:
   --dict:12/21(L)--   --dict:91/91(ro)(L)--   false   W   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   Subtype
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   runpdf   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   runpdf   runpdf   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1962   1   3   %oparray_pop   runpdf   runpdf   3   1   3   runpdf   %for_pos_int_continue   runpdf   runpdf   --dict:8/17(L)--   runpdf   32   %dict_continue   runpdf   runpdf
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:739/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:135/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:319/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:1/6(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.52: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 @ error/ghostscript-private.h/InvokeGhostscriptDelegate/171.

$ magick identify IVBF38119258.pdf[0]
IVBF38119258.pdf[0]=>IVBF38119258.pdf PDF 601x842 601x842+0+0 16-bit sRGB 24860B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

$ magick identify statement.pdf
statement.pdf[0] PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 1.8491MiB 0.040u 0:00.016
statement.pdf[1] PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 1.8491MiB 0.020u 0:00.012
statement.pdf[2] PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 1.8491MiB 0.020u 0:00.007
statement.pdf[3] PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 1.8491MiB 0.010u 0:00.003

The last file also throws the error in the uploader.  I have the latest Imagemagick and goastscript installed.

Any pointers to start digging here and also refine this question.

**UPDATES**

This works:

```
  pdf = MiniMagick::Image.new(current_path + '[0]')
```

This fails (with certain PDFs) with the GS error:

```
  pdf = MiniMagick::Image.new(current_path)
```

which now mimics my CLI experience.

Here is the file in question: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ncbsf73sdp8fec/fails.pdf?dl=0

Comment: That 'looks like' your PDF file is broken, hence you're getting an error, but it could just be a bug. Without access to the offending PDF file I can't tell. If you make the PDF file available I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I will try and sanitize the PDF and upload it. This error throws with all PDFs uploaded and most work fine from the CLI.

Comment: I just updated the question and included the file in question.  I have it working but not 100% sure this is stable.  I will need to add some logic in here to catch future bad files and skip the preview generation.

Answer (score 0):

For me page 1 works on the 9.52 release. Page 2, however, does throw an error, it's not quite the same as yours but it's similar 'typecheck in --.knownget--'

The current development branch instead throws warnings:

```
Page 2
   **** Error: Annotation array is not an array, ignoring it.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Annotation array is not an array, ignoring it.
               Output may be incorrect.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

If we look at the page dictionary for page 2 we see:

```
25 0 obj
<<
/CropBox [0 0 601 842]
/Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/ArtBox [0 0 601 842]
/Annots 17 0 R
/BleedBox [0 0 601 842]
/Resources 26 0 R
/TrimBox [0 0 601 842]
/Rotate 0
/MediaBox [0 0 601 842]
/Contents 73 0 R
>>
```

Knowing the problem is likely to be the Annotations, we then look at object 17 (the /Annots key) and we see:

```
17 0 obj
<<
/W [0 [595 631 631 315 293 629 629 631 293 679 681 571 631 631 631
631 631 631 631 764 608 606 630 276 689 630 607 811 276 517 553
610 693 629 389 408 966 679 680 742 630 627 587 598 587 781 587
630 981 545 349 456 358 334 856 574 630 631 315 726]]
/Type /Font
/CIDSystemInfo <<
/Ordering (Identity)
/Supplement 0
/Registry (Adobe)
>>
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/BaseFont /DejaVuSans
/FontDescriptor 15 0 R
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
>>
```

Now Annots are meant to be an array, and that's not an array, it's a dictionary, in fact it's a font dictionary. So basically, your PDF file is invalid, and that's why Ghostscript is throwing an error with it.

Now clearly we've recently added (yet more) heuristics to cope with PDF files broken in this particular way. In this case the commit in question is [this](https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=2844006034232cb95fdd295d7fedf5fed8390a8e) one. Note that this won't make the file 'correct', it just ignores the error! There's no real way for us to tell what the file **should** look like, so we've done our best to just carry on, and unlike a lot of other PDF consumers, we've warned you that something went wrong.

I notice that your PDF file claims to be produced by MacOS 10.15.5, but it's been modified by wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4. My guess would be it's the modification to the PDF which has broken it. However, looking at the file that was used to craft that fix, it was also produced by the same version of macOS but modified by Microsoft Word, so possibly the real bug is in Quartz.

Anyway, given that the PDF file is genuinely invalid you can either; get the PDF file fixed or build a local copy of Ghostscript from the current source, which will include the workaround for files broken in this fashion.

Or, of course, wait for the next release which will include this work-around, but that won't be until September.

### Edit

There's also a ShowAnnots switch, if you set `-dShowAnnots=false` then Ghostscript won't try to render any of the annotations, you could try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: The original version was a merged PDF in MacOS.  I used a PDF editor to sanitize the PDF.  Both versions fail on my end.  My version of GS is 9.52 also.  Wondering if there is a way to just make the PDF compliant?  I have seen other solutions where the preview is made for all pages.  Considering I am just making an image from the PDF I really don't care about the annotations etc.

Comment: You could overwrite the Annots key and its object in the page dictionary (with white space), or even simply corrupt the Annots key to be something else (eg Bnnots). Be aware that Annotations can make marks on the page (eg Highlight annotation, FreeText etc) so simply removing all annotations may not give you the result you expect, or want.

Comment: I am going to look into this.  I have related question that may help shed some light on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630317/carrierwave-create-image-preview-of-pdf